# Capturing a HTML form submit event that is triggered by a button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, events

This seems a straightforward problem but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have this code snippet that cannot be altered (CMS environment):

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  document.getElementById('myform').submit();
});
```

The HTML markup looks roughly like this:

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return helloworld(event);">
  <button id="mybutton">click to submit</button>
</form>
```

The only part where the markup cannot be changed is that the button must exist inside the form.

I have tried using `onsubmit`, tried using pure JS to capture the submit event, and also jQuery to capture the submit, none of which works:

```
function helloworld(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});

$('#myform').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Put together:

```js
//this function cannot be altered
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
 document.getElementById('myform').submit();
});

//anything below this line can be altered
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});

$('#myform').submit(function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});

function helloworld(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return helloworld(event);" action="https://stackoverflow.com/">
  <!-- this button must exist inside the form -->
  <button id="mybutton">click to submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7c8e3hns/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change `<button` to `<button type="button"`

Comment: Type of button has no relevance. You should test it on the fiddle first and see. Also, you can change button to any other element and the problem is still the same. I have already provided the answer.

Answer (score -1):

What about changing the event listener to listening for the `'click'` event instead of the `'submit'` event? And then instead of using `event.preventDefault();` use `event.stopPropagation();` and then doing what you desire?

According to the Mozilla docs(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

"`preventDefault()` method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be."

However in this case, it is already explicitly handled, so `stopPropagation()` should be appropriate.

Comment: As mentioned, the click event listener part CANNOT be changed. Tried stopPropagation() but it didn't work.

Comment: i was actually saying `document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});`
change the `submit` from this part to `click`

Comment: That'd just mean it'll be listening to a click event on the form (ie. everytime somebody clicks anywhere on the form). FWIW the answer is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Note: "If a form control (such as a submit button) has a `name` or `id` of `submit`, this method will mask the form's submit method."

Just place an invisible form input with `id` "submit" and `event.preventDefault()` will work, while not interfering all the other code in the `click` event.

Comment: If you read the link properly, the solution is to ADD a form control (not necessarily a button) with an id or name "submit", not change the original button with the click event.

Comment: Sorry, but all the relevant information must be in the SO answer, so, no, I won't be "reading the link *properly*" because it's an external link that I don't have access to.  Links expire.  You have provided the relevant information, so this is a valid answer, but you can't expect people to read external links "properly".

Comment: bit rude there, reign it in.  Glad you got your issue fixed.